# Flutter: Navigation issues between lifecycle of app

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, navigation

In my application, I'm using `routes` to navigate between pages.

Here's how I implemented route:

In `main.dart` file, I've defined routes like this:

```
bool session = await isValidSession(); //queries database and validate session

if (session) {
    _defaultHome = new HomePage();
}

final routes = {
    '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
    '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
    //several other pages
    '/logout' : (BuildContext context) => new LogoutPage(),
};
```

I've passed that route as argument to `runApp` method:

```
runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'My Application',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: _defaultHome,
    routes: routes,
));
```

The pages are navigatable through drawer menu. When user will `Tap` on a menu, this code executes and take customer to respective page.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/PAGE_NAME");
```

**Problematic Scenario:**

1. When user open app, fill up form and try to login
2. A function validates credentials and login user
3. Upon successful login, I've this code for navigating to `Home` page.

   ```
   Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed("/home");
   ```

According to official documentation of **[popAndPushNamed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html)** method,

> Pop the current route off the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context and push a named route in its place.

So according to my understanding, `popAndPushNamed` is supposed to remove `login` page from context and will navigate to `home` page.

It **doesn't work** as expected, it navigates to `home` page but doesn't remove `login` page from context, because pressing back button, takes back to login page (even the form is in filled state).

**Alternatively,** if I `pop` current context and `push` to new page then it works as expected.

```
Navigator.pop(context); 
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/home");
```

But there's **still an issue** with this approach, when I Tap on `back` button from `home` page. The screen goes blank, instead of quitting the app.

**Questions:**

1. How do I properly remove `login` page from context? (if user press back button then app quits)
2. When user logout, how do I remove all pages from context and navigate to `login` page? (already tried but it doesn't work in my case)

   ```
   Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
   ```

Comment: You can use: Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login'); This will replace the page you are for the new one.

Comment: tried but doesn't work, maybe there is something wrong with context but I'm unsure

Comment: Post the part of your code where you are calling the Navigator

Comment: Currently, I have this code in my drawer, for logout `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/logout");` and it is inside `onTap` method.

Comment: The context is inside build() method, if you are calling another method you might need to pass down the context argument

Comment: Please explain it with an example. For instance, if I open drawer from `home` page, and click on `logout`, how should I pass context?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for logout :

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
    ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for the logout scenario. Is it possible to pass name like `/login` instead of passing page? Also how should I move to `/home` page from `/login` page so going back quits app.